# adding alias in a file and run from cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, alias

I have put my alias in C:/bin/.bash_aliases file as follows:

```
alias gmvn='mvn clean install -DskipTests'
alias h=history
alias c=clear
```

I have set path in environment variable as `C:/bin/.bash_aliases;`.

Now when I open cygwin in windows and execute gmvn, I get the following:

`-bash: gmvn: command not found`

Comment: Did you do `source ~/.bash_aliases ` before trying the command `gmvn`

Comment: @Inian- I have to add user defined alias in .bashrc file of cygwin. It worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cygwin contains .bashrc file which is for adding and using alias. I added all my aliases in that file. It worked.

Comment: You don't have to do that. You can still have it in `.bash_aliases` and add a line at the end in `.bashrc` at last for `source ~/.bash_aliases`, so that whenever an interactive shell is started (`.bashrc` will be sourced during this), your aliases are also expanded